# Import Multibit HD Wallets

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery, multibit-hd

I have 4 wallets in Multibit HD.

I have password, secret words and time stamps for each wallet.

I want to move to a new computer, I know that I can use RESTORE button in Multibit HD. but I am afraid of losing my money.

My question is: I know that Multibit HD stores all data in:
C:\Users\username\Appdata\Roaming\MultibitHD

If i copy that folder to the new computer, can I open my wallets without need to restoring?

Answer (score 1):

MultiBit HD developer here.

There is a lot of information about restoring wallets in the Help within the wallet and on the website:

https://multibit.org/en/help/hd0.1/restore-wallet.html

https://multibit.org/en/help/hd0.1/files.html

The cloud backup folders are there to allow full restoration of a wallet if you know the wallet words. They will restore contacts, notes, exchange rates - all of it.

If you are confident in copying files around on your machine (many users have trouble with this so we guide them away from it) then it is safe to perform a blanket copy of the Roaming files to the other machine. Make sure to re-create the cloud backup directory and populate it as well.

As is always the case, make sure you keep your wallet words safe so that if it goes wrong (lightning strike right in the middle of the copy?) you can always recover your private keys.